# Docker-compose with Gradle, Spring Boot and PostgreSQL: How to properly handle build and startup sequence?

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, gradle, docker-compose

I'm working on a Spring Boot pet-project with PostgreSQL as the database, and I'm using Docker Compose to orchestrate the containers. The issue I'm facing is that the `RUN ./gradlew build` command in my Dockerfile is getting executed before the PostgreSQL container is fully up and running, causing my tests to fail during the build process.

Dockerfile:

```
# Build stage
FROM amazoncorretto:17 AS build
WORKDIR /app
COPY ../ /app
RUN ./gradlew build

# Runtime stage
FROM amazoncorretto:17 AS runtime
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build /app/build/libs/*.jar /app/app.jar
CMD ["java", "-jar", "/app/app.jar"]
```

docker-compose.yaml:

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  postgres:
    image: 'postgres:latest'
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: ${POSTGRES_DB}
      POSTGRES_USER: ${POSTGRES_USER}
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
    ports:
      - '5432:5432'
    healthcheck:
      test: pg_isready -U ${POSTGRES_USER} -d ${POSTGRES_DB}
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 5

  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: docker/Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      postgres:
        condition: service_healthy
    environment:
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL: jdbc:postgresql://postgres:5432/${POSTGRES_DB}
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME: ${POSTGRES_USER}
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD: ${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
    ports:
      - '8080:8080'
```

I've tried using `depends_on` and `healthcheck` in `docker-compose.yaml`, but the issue remains.

So, my questions are:

1. What is the best way to ensure that the PostgreSQL container is fully ready before running the `./gradlew build` command?
2. Is there a more "Docker-native" or "Spring-native" way to handle this dependency during the build process?

Comment: How does building your application jar file require a database?  Can you fix that?  The Dockerfile can never call another container.

Answer (score 0):

As of Spring Boot 3.1, Docker Compose is supported. Spring Boot will start the container for you and also inject any necessary credentials or connection details into the Spring `Environment` which allows other libraries such as Spring Data to create its beans.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.docker-compose

Spring Boot's Docker Compose support can also be used in tests.